# Master theorem for $T(n) = 9T(\frac{n}{3}) +4n^6$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-complexity

based on master theorem, I arrived at $$n^{2} ,f(n)=4n^6$$.
So is the answer $$\theta(4n^6)$$ or is it just $$\theta(n^6)$$.
And also, can this be solved with substitution method?

Comment: You should *never* write multiplicative constants in a $\Theta()$, $O()$ or $\Omega()$ notation. so, no "4".

Comment: @ClementC. thank you.i tried to solve using substitution method but got nowhere.Can you show me the steps to solve it with substitution method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint for you - after $k$ substitutions you should have:

$$T(n) = 9^kT(\frac{n}{3^k}) + 4n^6\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c^i$$

where $c$ is a constant.